# Assigning resolver data to string key

Tags: angular

I've been learning how to use the resolver in the Angular router, and I'm having a discrepancy with the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard) that I can't figure out.

As far as I can tell, I've copied the resolver from the docs/guide other than the docs using a Promise, and my using an Observer:

```
export class OrgResolver implements Resolve<Org> {

    constructor(private router: Router, private orgService: OrgService) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Org> {
        return this.orgService.getOrgData(route.params['org']).map((org: Org) => {
            if (org === null) {
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
                return null;
            } else {
                return org;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

However, in my component, when I try to access the data:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe((data: { org: Org }) => { this.org = data.org; console.log(data); });
}
```

I see that `data` is an object with only one key, 0. In the docs, the key is somehow set to 'crisis', but I can't seem to figure out how. I feel like I have to assume `data` may contain other keys in other situations, so there's no way for me to know for sure that 0 is the key I want.

Am I missing something about using the resolver?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realize that the problem was in the route configuration. Initially, I was passing `resolve` an array:

```
resolve: [OrgResolver]
```

I didn't realize I wanted to pass it an object with the key being how it'd be represented in `data`:

```
resolve: { org: OrgResolver }
```